# How to use multitouch for pictures

Tags: java, android, eclipse, zooming, multi-touch

I'm making an app in which I would like to `implement an offline map service for the city Rome`, I thought the simplest way to do this was to implement an high-resolution map-picture of the city, but now I am getting into two problems:

- If I add a picture in eclipse to my app it is being scaled down to the size of an icon and when I scale it up again it has very low resolution, how can this be solved?
- Do you have any experience with multi touch or zooming possibilites? Because when you have the map people would like to zoom in to see street-names in detail. I know you have to give the fingers coordinates x,x and y,y but is this the easiest way and how should I continue?

Comment: as for the map problem have you thought about downloading the image to the users phone the first time they use it and just storing it there that way you avoid the re-scaling of it

Comment: As the app should be working fully offline I don't think that would be the most efficient way :P, Have you any other idea? Thanks in advance

Comment: but they must be online at least once to download the app so when they start it up the very first time you download it and store it then and then you check if the image exists and if so you load it up

Comment: try this  google http://code.google.com/p/android-touchexample/

Comment: I just deleted my online serverspace, do you know how I could set up a download-service for the map for free and the check for the map?